# How to align by 4 for all label addresses and function addresses in assembly?

Tags: assembly, memory-alignment, riscv, gnu-assembler, riscv32

RISC-V jump/call instructions need the target address to be aligned to multiple of 4.
Hence I align my code as below with p2align for every function and label:

```
.p2align 2
    trap_routine: /* trap routine */
        nop;
        csrr t0, mcause;
        ...
        li t2, 4;
        beq t2, t1, LB_uart1_intr;
    
        /* HACK: if not uart1, for gpio21 interrupt */
        j LB_gpio21_intr;
    
    .p2align 2
    LB_uart1_intr: /* Uart1 interrupt */
    
        j LB_trap_routine_end;
    
    .p2align 2
    LB_gpio21_intr: /* Gpio21 interrupt */
```

Though above works, I had to do it for all functions and labels
**Is there a way to instruct the assembler to give all functions and labels addresses alignment to 4-byte boundaries?**  Without having to manually use `.p2align` in front of each.

Comment: What are you doing that mis-aligns the code?  Code without compressed instructions should simply stay 4 byte aligned.

Comment: If the processor in question doesn't support the C (compressed instruction) extension, it should not be fed them, so change your build options to avoid use of compressed instructions, in compiler & assembler output as well as library choice.  Otherwise, you'll have ongoing problems beyond alignment.

Comment: @sniper, you might consider making a post on [binutils mailing list](https://sourceware.org/mailman/listinfo/binutils). If this is indeed the case maintainers will probably add it as an options. Theres alot of activity around RISV5 now.

Answer (score 1):

No assembler option that I know of, but I didn't check the man page.

> RISC-V jump/call instructions need the target address to be aligned to multiple of 4

Is that true even when using RV32C compressed (2-byte) instructions?  If not, then you don't need to do anything unless you're mixing code and data.  If instructions are always 4 bytes wide, then aligning by 4 at the top of `.text` means the start of every line after that will also be aligned by 4, unless you manually misalign by mixing in a `.byte` or `.short` into the middle of your code.

But if RV32C still requires 4-byte alignment while some instructions are only 2 bytes wide, then yeah, you'd need to worry about alignment.

---

You could make a macro called L(x) or something that expands to `.p2align 2` / `x`.

Some projects (like glibc) do that so they can prefix labels with `.L`, or to have a macro to declare an exported label without having to manually repeat the label name in a `.globl` directive as well as an actual label.

Then your source would look like

```
#define Lalign(x) .p2align 2; x:

Lalign(trap_routine)
...

Lalign(LB_uart1_intr)
...
```

I used a C preprocessor macro for `Lalign(x)`.  It's probably doable with a pure GAS `.macro` / `.endm`, if you want this in a `.s` file that you won't run through the C preprocessor while building.

Comment: Is that true even when using RV32C compressed (2-byte) instructions? yes based on my observation. It causes exception due to misaligned target address & its due to mix of compressed and non compressed instructions. Not due to data and code mix.